# While(true) loop get stuck in Windows Service without any log or eventLog

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows Service with a main method that includes 5 tasks:

- 4 System.Timers.Timer()
- 1 method with infinit loop While(true) handled by a separat thread

N.B: before each method execution a description like "Send command starting now ..." is written in .log file

Yesterday when I checked the log, I noted that all 4 timers methods logs into log file and execute the code, but the method with the infinite loop While(true) logged nothing.

Could you provide me your suggestion about what can cause the infinite loop?

```
 private void StartThread(){
        if (_Thread != null){
            if (_Thread.IsAlive){
                return;
            }
        }

         Log.Write("thread started.");
        _Thread = new Thread(SchedulerWorker);
        _Thread.IsBackground = true;
        _Thread.Name = "scheduler thread";
        _Thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        _Thread.Start();
    }

    private void SchedulerWorker(){
        while (true){
            try{
                DoScheduleWork();
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                Log.Write("Worker exception : " +  ex);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(TIMER_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would need to show the code for your infinite loop, as lets face it, its name does imply it would get stuck!

Comment: -1: More information is needed - showing some code for the loop would help.

Comment: *"what can cause the infinite loop to get stuck"* :D ...Is it possible the thread with the infinite loop doesn't get started? That seems an obvious explanation given you say it logs something as its first action. Also, is it possible it's cacheing writing to the log file, so since it goes into an infinite loop it never flushes to disk (or wherever).

Comment: There's something deeply amusing about someone complaining about an infinite loop "getting stuck"...

Comment: It could be wonderful exeption inside infinitive loop and service stops. Show some code to clear minds whats going on in loop.

Comment: An infinite number of possible reasons exist. Post your code to find out which you were lucky enough to stumble upon.

Comment: Hi all , i have add the main method squeleton

Comment: It could also be useful to know what happens in DoScheduleWork()

Comment: many thanks Phillip for your interest but it's a huge treatment in my case it'll not be useful

Comment: [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        private void DoScheduleWork()
        {
            StopXXXX();
            StartXXXX();
            DoXXXX();
            HandleSleepMode();
        }

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check `Log` object for multithread support. If it works in main thread does not mean that it works in another thread well at same time. When work with multiple threads you always need to keep in mind about concurrency and other important rules. At least, may be you should place `Log` into `lock` statement (I don't know internal structure of your `Log` object).

Second, don't think that `Log` not throws exceptions or exceptions don't exists inside `catch` block. Is quite possible that thread crashes here:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Write("Worker exception : " +  ex);
    }
```

Third, try simpliest and safest logging first for your debug purposes. Usually Windows Services logs their events into system journal. But it not well suited for debugging, it is rather a part of Service "interface". Try to use `Trace` class from `System.Diagnostics`.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Trace.WriteLine("Worker exception : " +  ex);
   }
```

**For multithreaded applications you need more accurately write, verify and debug every step of your code before think that it works as expected. Multithreading in most cases significantly increases the complexity of development.**

Creation of Service applications is also not a trivial task. For example using of forms in Services is strongly discouraged and complicates debugging.